# Insert span with class and id in CKEditor5 produces error when pasting

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I'm developing a CKEditor5 plugin that requires me to insert a span with an id and some classes.

This is my code to allow that:

```
editor.model.schema.register('span', {
    inheritAllFrom: '$block',
    allowIn: ['paragraph'],
    allowAttributes: ['id', 'class']
});
editor.conversion.elementToElement({model: 'span', view: 'span'});          
editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute({model: 'class', view: 'class'});
editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute({model: {name: 'span', key: 'id'}, view: 'id'});
```

This allows me to insert the span without any problem. My problem is that if I paste some content with a span (for example, a text with background color set in the FontBackGroundColor plugin) and then press backspace, I get this error:

```
VM28478:5 Uncaught CKEditorError: move-operation-node-into-itself: Trying to move a range of nodes into one of nodes from that range. Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-move-operation-node-into-itself

    at cc._validate (<anonymous>:5:277330)
    at Jc.on.priority (<anonymous>:5:324234)
    at Jc.fire (<anonymous>:5:101659)
    at Jc.(anonymous function) [as applyOperation] (<anonymous>:5:115956)
    at gc.move (<anonymous>:5:289708)
    at gc.insert (<anonymous>:5:287384)
    at t (<anonymous>:5:319802)
    at <anonymous>:5:319915
    at Jc.change (<anonymous>:5:324808)
    at Nc (<anonymous>:5:318986)
```

Is my approach correct? I tried to read the documentation but I don't think I got it quite right.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not best suited for the CKEditor 5. In CKEditor 5 there is [implemented a custom model](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/overview.html#design) which separates some feature's view from how it is stored in the model. So when implementing a model for a CKEditor 5 feature you should rather think of what this solves and not how it is represented in HTML. This approach requires a bit more work when defining model behavior but this design enables CKEditor 5 to work in collaboration.

Now that being said, there are many cases when one just want to retain all `<span>` with their styling, classes and custom attributes. In CKEditor 5 you should rather map some styles, classes or attributes to model elements or `$text` node attributes to match feature semantics - not the HTML data.

Keeping in mind that this is not an ideal solution for CKEditor you should

1. Define some attributes on text that would store your attributes by extending the built-in `$text`.

   ```js
   editor.model.schema.extend( '$text', {
       allowAttributes: [ 'spanId', 'spanClass' ]
   } );
   ```
2. Provide conversion for [upcast](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcasthelpers-UpcastHelpers.html#function-elementToAttribute) (view to model) and [downcast](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcasthelpers-DowncastHelpers.html#function-attributeToElement) (model to view) that will map your `<span>` to model text attributes. You can read more on this in [conversion guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/conversion/conversion-introduction.html). But something like below should work:

   ```js
   editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).elementToAttribute( {
       view: {
           name: 'span',
           attributes: {
               'id': /.+/
           }
       },
       model: {
           key: 'spanId',
           value: viewElement => viewElement.getAttribute( 'id' )
       }
   } );

   editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' ).attributeToElement( {
       model: 'spanId',
       view: ( modelAttributeValue, viewWriter ) => {
           return viewWriter.createAttributeElement( 'span', {
               id: modelAttributeValue
           } );
       }
   } );
   ```

Now, the reason your setup didn't work is that you inserted block into another block - which isn't supported in the CKEditor 5 model. Most HTML inline elements are usally converted to some text attributes thus requires `element-to-attribute` conversion.